# Limit access to an Azure site to only the VPN connected computers

Tags: azure, vpn

this might be a dumb question.

is it possible to restrict the access to my Azure website http://sitename.cloudapp.net so that only the computers connected to my VPN will be able to access the site?

I use cloud services, and i have a vpn on my local computer(for now). the idea is(if possible), to have a connection between my vpn (which is local network) AND my cloudservice. Then allow the site access to only the computers within the vpn

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a VPN and disable the public endpoints, so only machines within the VPN have access, but I think this is only available for VM's and Cloud Services - and not Windows Azure Websites. You don't say which you use.

> "[Windows Azure Virtual Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx) provides you with the capability
>   to extend your network into Windows Azure..."

Channel 9 offers some useful guides
[Windows Azure Virtual Machines and Virtual Networks](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/Learn-2012TechEd-EU/VirtualMachines)

Comment: thanks for the response. forgot to include what i use: cloud service.. i've updated my question